# Completely disable/block Visual Studio updates?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I've used Visual Studio 2019 for a couple of months and I enjoy the new flat interface and all,
but I don't like the fact that I **must** update to a new version in middle of developing an app.

I am thinking on going back to Visual Studio 2010 but that doesn't solve anything, it just
introduces more problems.

So any ways on dealing with this? A registry key or something that prevents the Electron installer
from connecting to the internet or trying to update altogether.

Comment: FYI "Electron" sounds like Visual Studio **Code**, which is different from VS

Comment: @HansKeﬆing the Visual Studio Installer was an Electron-based app until the 16.9 release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried Tools => Options... => Environment => Product Updates?

[image]